# SQL query, excluding first five records

Tags: mysql, sql

`$com = $conn->prepare("select * from comments where com_vid_id=? order by likes desc");`

On this query if my result is:  **A, D, C, G, B, K, R, T, Q, Z, V**   ....

I want to make the result like this:   **K, R, T, Q, Z, V**   ....

How to pass first five records in query ?

Comment: Limit ,5 something like that

Comment: You select all columns from your table, and your output is like that? Hmm...

Answer (score 2):

use LIMIT and OFFSET

```
$com = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE com_vid_id=? ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 5");
```

Comment: oh yeaa how can i forgot this, thank you my friend :)